# What is Edm.DateTime?

Tags: labor

I'm using [this dataset](https://developer.dol.gov/expanding-growth/oui-inital-claims/) which has a 'Week' property. I can see its type is `Edm.DateTime`, but unfortunately I don't know this type.

How can I convert it convert to a timestamp or date?

Example:

- `/Date(-94176000000)/`
- `/Date(1478304000000)/`

Comment: [unix time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) with milliseconds? https://www.unixtimestamp.com/index.php

Answer (score 1):

These are the number of milliseconds after (or before, for negative values) January 1st, 1970, midnight UTC, which is the [Unix epoch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time).

You can use a website like [this one](https://www.epochconverter.com/); it shows the current time in *seconds* since the epoch, but it converts milliseconds as well.

Your first example, `-94176000000`, converts to `Saturday, January 7, 1967 0:00:00`; it's quite rare to see negative Unix timestamps but in case of historical data, it happens. If I browse the data [here](https://devtools.dol.gov/APISampler/Home/SearchIndex), it also starts in January 1967.

How to convert these depends on the programming language. In Java, the [default constructor for Date](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#Date-long-) accepts exactly this format; C# has e.g. a [`DateTimeOffset.FromUnixTimeMilliseconds`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetimeoffset.fromunixtimemilliseconds?view=netcore-3.1) method.